# How to use a Base64 SVG placeholder inside a picture tag

Tags: html, image, svg, base64, lazy-loading

So far I've been using the method below [1] to preload the required empty SVG viewbox ratio on my lazy loaded `img` tags before the javascript overwrites them with the actual image. This is so that the page does not repaint and looks less jittery. This works well on simple `img` tags with no errors as per the following article:

[https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/#article-header-id-2][1]

The problem I have is when doing this inside a `picture` tag. The `srcset` property doesn't seem to like base64, i get the following errors:

```
Failed parsing 'srcset' attribute value since it has an unknown descriptor.
Dropped srcset candidate "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg"
```

1. What's going on here ?
2. Is it possible to use this technique with `picture` tag `srcset` attributes?
3. Is there any way of achieving a similar effect with the right syntax?

Comment: That doesn't seem the syntax allowed with srcset. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: ok thanks, is there any way to do something similar with srcset?

Comment: you need to use actual files with srcset. That's what it's for. Why on earth would you want to use srcset with SVG anyway? SVG is resolution independent by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`srcset` doesn't allow that syntax. Use separate `img` tags instead

Answer (score 0):

Stuck in the same "svg placeholder in srcset" issue as you.
Actually you CAN resolve it by replacing ' ' to '%20':

```
svgString = svgString.replace(/ /g,'%20');
```

and you'll have properly sized container as set in viewbox. Also Chrome won't throw errors.